# Pyspark handle German Timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, type-conversion, timestamp

I have problems handling a german timestamp in PySpark. In my Data, the 'dd-MMM-yyy HH:mm:ss' time format is used. But the month is in German (MAI vs MAY):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('25-MAI-2020 13:30:30',)],['Test'])
```

I am trying to work with the data but pyspak isn't able to interpret it correctly:

```
df.select(to_date(col('Test'), 'dd-MMM-yyy HH:mm:ss'),to_timestamp(col('Test'),'dd-MMM-yyy HH:mm:ss')).show(1)
```

I already tried setting locale to German time, but that didn't work for me.
Any tips?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom `DateTimeFormatter` to parse these german months as below-

> Please note this is written in scala

```scala
 val df = Seq("25-MAI-2020 13:30:30").toDF("Test")
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +--------------------+
      * |Test                |
      * +--------------------+
      * |25-MAI-2020 13:30:30|
      * +--------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Test: string (nullable = true)
      *
      */
```

```scala
    def parseGermanTimeStamp(toParse: String) = {
      import java.lang.{Long => JLong}
      // improve this list for all months
      val monthTexts = java.util.Collections.singletonMap(JLong.valueOf(5), "MAI")
      val formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("dd-")
        .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, monthTexts)
        .appendPattern("-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        .toFormatter(Locale.GERMANY)
      val ldt = java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(toParse, formatter)
      ldt.toString
    }

    val getTime = udf((str: String) => parseGermanTimeStamp(str))
    df.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp(getTime($"Test"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +--------------------+-------------------+
      * |Test                |timestamp          |
      * +--------------------+-------------------+
      * |25-MAI-2020 13:30:30|2020-05-25 13:30:30|
      * +--------------------+-------------------+
      */
```

Hope this is useful for someone!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not "fancy" but it works. It might help someone in the future looking for the same question:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn('Test',F.regexp_replace(df.Test,'MRZ','MAR'))
df = df.withColumn('Test',F.regexp_replace(df.Test,'MAI','MAY'))
df = df.withColumn('Test',F.regexp_replace(df.Test,'OKT','OCT'))
df = df.withColumn('Test',F.regexp_replace(df.Test,'DEZ','DEC'))
```